# PHP code in mail body - Rules

Tags: 7, rules

In the Rules module, is it possible to write php code in mail body?
There is no input format beneath body text area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to use PHP, I suggest you create your own rule, using [`hook_action_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_action_info/7).

You have a good example in the [Examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) module.

Comment: Just for reference, the example is in the **Actions** submodule of the Examples module.